# added dtf layer, doesn't align with SHP layers

Tags: qgis

I've built a NY basic state map in QGIS using .shp files of counties, all in NAD83/UTM 18N projection. I downloaded a file of hospitals with lat/long coordinates and converted it to a delimited text file. When I go to Add Layer --> Add DTL and confirm the file, the lat/long, and select the projection, my facility points load... but far to the southwest of the rest of the map. If I zoom way out, I see the hospitals of NY floating far below the state, in about Guatemala.

What step am I missing to get my point data to overlay properly with the rest of the map?

```
FacID    Name   Short   Address City    Latitude    Longitude
1   Albany Medical Center Hospital  HOSP    43 New Scotland Avenue  Albany  42.65337    -73.773834
2   Albany Medical Center - South Clinical Campus   HOSP    25 Hackett Blvd Albany  42.645485   -73.77829
4   Albany Memorial Hospital    HOSP    600 Northern Blvd   Albany  42.674271   -73.749268
```

Comment: Show a few lines of your text file.

Comment: Could it be wrong long/lat order?

Comment: Tried reversing it just in case -- shows up the same, weirdly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV data you supplied is correct. Assigning EPSG:4326 to the **layer**, it loads fine on a OpenStreetMap background with the **project** CRS set to EPSG:3857:

[image]

So you must have done something wrong with the shapefiles if they don't align.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the advice. AndreJ was right -- the problem was in my county .shp files, somehow. I downloaded a new set from the state, and the hospital data points are now loading correctly over them.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the sample of your dtf above, you need to specify your delimiter as a tab.  It's likely set to a comma or pipe.
[image]

**Update:** Are you trying to bring in your lat/long file into a projected coordinate system?  That could be your problem.  You'll need to bring it into a GCS (WGS84 lat/long most likely).  Please let us know if any of these suggestions work for you.

Comment: Thanks for all these. Away from my QGIS-bearing laptop for a few days but will try all of the above over the weekend. I agree that it could be a problem with the .shp files over which these coordinates are being layered, or a projection issue. I believe the data are importing with tab selected as delimiter, though.

Comment: Try bringing in your points in a GCS (WGS84 or similar), then project them to your coordinate system.